# How to display remote image in php webpage

Tags: php, curl, web, header

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/xxx.png'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($curl);
header('Content-type:image/PNG');
echo $result;
curl_close($curl);
```

The function header() didn't work, it always dispalyed binary data.
Maybe because I used these codes in the middle of webpage what has existed.
The webpage outputed some texts before header(), so it didn't work.

I want to get image by url, and display image directly, no need save file to disc.
So how can I do ? Please help me !!!

—————————

I need set referer, so I used curl.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you would rather output with PHP instead of basic HTML?

Comment: Because I pirated link and I need set referer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the image directly as follows:

```
<img src ='http://www.example.com/xxx.png'>
```

Comment: I need set referer.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: I need to use images of other website, but those images are anti pirate link, so I must change referer of Httpheader into that website. Then my website can use them.

Comment: Can you show us the image that you want to show in your site?